# Updating code to better structure in python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, code-duplication

I have a code that calculates some stuff and has a lot of hardcoded values and duplicity, I just need help in arranging it in such a way It wouldn't look messy.

This is not my actual code but basic structure of my code

```
def my_code():
    a = [func1(x),func2(x),func3(x)]
    return a

def func1(x):
    func1_x =  #calculation using x formula
    func1_dict = {}
    func1["name"] = #some f1hardcoded name
    func1["school"] = "some f1hardcoded value"
    func1["school_address"] = "some f1hardcoded value"
    func1["score_in_written"] = f" func1 student scored {func1_x} percentage "
    func1["score_in_perc"] = func1_x

def func2(x):
    func2_x = #some calculation using y formula
    func2_dict = {}
    func2["name"] = #some f2hardcoded name
    func2["school"] = "some f2hardcoded value"
    func2["school_address"] = "some f2hardcoded value"
    func2["score_in_written"] = f" func1 student scored {func2_x} percentage "
    func2["score_in_perc"] = func2_x

def func3(x):
    func3_x = #some calculation using z formula
    func3_dict = {}
    func3["name"] = # f3 related some hardcoded name
    func3["school"] = " f3 related some hardcoded value"
    func3["school_address"] = " f3 related hardcoded value"
    func3["score_in_written"] = f" func1 student scored {func3_x} percentage "
    func3["score_in_perc"] = func3_x
```

Hardcoded values basically would not be changed for any x value in a particular function, only the score in percentage and score_in_written would change.

As I have many functions like this (till func9), is there any way I can change this into better code structure?
Is there any way I can make this code a little tidy and clean?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a class to structure the repeated values like this:

```
class StudentAcademics:
  def __init__(self, name, school, schoolAddress, score):
    self.name = name
    self.school = school
    self.schoolAddress = schoolAddress
    self.scoreInWritten = f" func1 student scored {score} percentage "
    self.scoreInPercent = score

score =  #calculation using x formula
student_academics_1 = StudentAcademics("John", "xyz school", "xyz address", score)

score =  #calculation using y formula
student_academics_2 = StudentAcademics("Tom", "abc school", "abc address", score)

score =  #calculation using z formula
student_academics_2 = StudentAcademics("Bill", "jkl school", "jkl address", score)
```

Now when you want to access the data again you can simply do:

```
print("name {} studied at {}".format(student_academics_1.name, student_academics_1.school))
```

Let me know if you have any questions further.

Comment: This isn't what I've been looking for but this actually cleared a lot of my doubts related to classes, Thank you. The hardcoded values are not something that I wanna pass as a parameter, they will be same for all the x values in a particular function. so for func1 there will be some hardcoded values that would be same for all x and similarly in func2 and func3 there will be some hardcoded values that will be same for all x values.

Comment: This probably doesn't make sense here, but in my actual code which has the same structure as this it does

Answer (score 0):

What you could be looking at is creating multiple classes with having a class for each subsection of similar operations. Then create the main class that combines all these classes. That way it looks clean and structured. Just read yourself into python classes and how to create objects.

Comment: Hi, sure I will try this. If you could provide a small example code snippet, it would mean a lot. Thanks for your answer, I will read about this surely.